# adb failed to stat APK: No such file or directory

Tags: android-studio, pycharm, adb, appium-android

I am a MacOS user, and I am trying to access a specific activity within an app (the app is the APK file). The emulator I am running from Android Studio is Pixel 3a XL. I have a Python client connected to the Appium server. I am using the Appium GUI server to run the code and using PyCharm to write the code. Prior to running the Appium GUI server, Android emulator, and PyCharm code, I was using a different APK file then switched to a new one. I typed in the command, 'appium-doctor --android' to verify that my environment variables and adb path is correct and there were checkmarks indicating that it was. After my PyCharm test failed, I used the terminal to install the emulator and received a new error stating that there is no such file or directory even though my path to my APK is correct.

Python Code:

> from appium import webdriver

> desired_capabilities = {
> "deviceName": "Pixel_3a_XL",
> "appPackage": "edu.psu.hhd.hdfs.jpm165.genericsurveyapp2",
> "appActivity": ".SplashScreenActivity",
> "platformName": "Android",
> "app":"/Users/jkenglish/Desktop/Surge_Projects/app-debug-signed-2-22-22.apk"
> }

> #Driver Instance

> webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desired_capabilities)

Terminal Command:

> adb -s emulator-5554 install /Users/jkenglish/Desktop/Surge_Projects/app-debug-signed-2-22-2022.apk

> Performing Streamed Install
> adb: failed to stat /Users/jkenglish/Desktop/Surge_Projects/app-debug-signed-2-22-2022.apk: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

It seems the file does not exist.

Run these

```
f='/Users/jkenglish/Desktop/Surge_Projects/app-debug-signed-2-22-2022.apk'
if [[ -e "$f" ]]
then
    adb -s emulator-5554 install "$f"
else
    printf 'ERROR: %s does not exist\n' "$f"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Do some simple checks

- If the file exists in the specified location (you've confirmed this already)
- The file directory path is correctly written
- If the file path contains special characters, use quotes around the path
- If adb is not working when referenced via environment variable try using the full path of adb. If the adb directory paths also contains spaces or special characters, use quotes around the path here also